# How can I search for edited rows on Sheets to compare the values and change the timestamp on different columns accordingly?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been looking endlessly for a method to compare values on different columns in the same row, to know which cell I should update.

The speradsheet is a simple model of stock management (it's quite simple and I've been doing it manually), but I wanted a 'faster'(*) ou automated way of updating the amounts os each item, and the timestamps (which are two: one for adding units to the stock, and one for withdrawing).

The obstacles so far are:

1. The `onEdit()` function won't work on automated changes like macros, so it's off the table;
2. I need to scan the whole spreadsheet to find every filled cell on column D, which carries the value i'm adding to or subtracting from my column C;
   -For this i have already setup do filter the column 'from Z to A' to get all the cells with values on them, but the amount of items changed can vary, so i cant set a search with a fixed number of rows.
3. Since my sheet has over 90 entries (likely to increase) of at least 6 columns each, a `for` loop with `if` statements takes too long, (*)but execution time is not exactly the main concern right now.

The code is as follows, and I'll be attaching a picture of the sheet I'm working with.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function geral() {
  filtro();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=C2+D2');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('G2:G92'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2:G').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G:G').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
 
  //adds the input OR output timestamp depending on the value in D column
  //!!WORK IN PROGRESS!! --> here's where it gets tricky, and that's what I got so far (which doesn't work)

/*
  for (var i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
    spreadsheet.getRange('J2').setValue("TESTE");
    var cell1 = spreadsheet.getRange('????').getValue(); //from this point on, I don't know how to proceed
    var cell2 = spreadsheet.getRange('????').getValue();
    spreadsheet.getRange('J2').setValue("TESTE2");
    if(cell1 > cell2){
      spreadsheet.getRange('????').activate();
      spreadsheet.getActiveCell().setValue(new Date());
    }
    else if(cell1 < cell2){
      spreadsheet.getRange('????').activate();
      spreadsheet.getActiveCell().setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
*/
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2:D').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  
};


function filtro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().sort(4, false);
};
```

**EDIT**: With my review after @IrvingJayG.'s comment, I noticed a few mistakes and unnecessary extra steps, so instead of doing all the copy-paste-delete dance and then compare results, I'd go for the pseudocode below:

```
//Ci's value pre-exists in the sheet, where i is the row index
//manually input Di value
//set formula for Gi = Ci+Di
//and then compare either Ci and Gi, or Di and 0 
    if(Di > 0){
    //the following steps can be defined as a new function for each case, (e.g. updateIn() and updateOut())
        copy Gi to Ci;
        update Ei with new Date(); 
        delete Gi and Di;
    }
    else if(Di < 0){
        copy Gi to Ci;
        update Fi with new Date();
        delete Gi and Di;
    }
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't solve my problem, just simplifies the code by a lot.

[Sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqNP0.png)

Comment: The onEdit trigger only responds to user edits.  It does not responed to changes due to formulas or other scripts.

Comment: If you looking to run functions using onEdit trigger then I suggest that you discontinue the use of activate and other features found in macros because they just consume a lot of time which is something you don't have in onEdit functions which must complete in 30 seconds.

Comment: Can you share a simple step-by-step process (e.g. data on row 2) on how you would add or subtract a value from Column D to a value from column C and when to place an input or output timestamp? This is to make sure we get the complete visualization of the process you want to automate

Comment: @IrvinJayG. OK, as I was typing my explanation I saw I was taking some unnecessary extra steps, but I'll describe my first thoughts anyway, and then what I just realized, which isn't a solution to the problem yet. 
First I would manually input the values on column D, which can be positive or negative (so, for row 2 = 5). Then i set G2 to add C2 and D2, and copy/paste it to C2, disposing of G2 (first mistake). After that, i'd compare C2 and D2 (2nd mistake), and if C2 > D2, i'd update the timestamp on E2, but if C2 < D2, then i'd update F2. +

Comment: @IrvinJayG.  By now you can see what I was doing wrong, because i just needed to compare D2 with 0 (if greater, update E2; if less, update F2) or C2 with G2 (in both cases it only updates the timestamp after C2 is updated as well).  However I still don't know how to check every row on D to see if they're null or not and then compare it, to see which timestamp column needs to be updated.

Comment: @MetaMan yes, I've seen this information in many other topics, which is why I dropped it and started looking for non-triggered ways to do it. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @Rodrigo Biffi Thanks for the additional info. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RECOMMENDATION:**

I've created a sample sheet (based on your attached example sheet) with 6 rows of data and with 4 random sample cell values on Column D. Then, I've created a sample script below, where you can use a reference:

*NOTE:* *This script will scan every row on your sheet that has data (e.g. if you have 30 rows of data, it will scan every row one-by-one until it reaches the 30th row) and may slow-down once you have bunch of data on it. That's the catch because it's an expected behavior*

**SAMPLE SHEET:**

[image]

**SCRIPT:**

```
  function onOpen() { //[OPTIONAL] Created a custom menu "Timestamp" on your Spreadsheet, where you can run the script
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('Timestamp')
          .addItem('Automate Timestamp', 'mainFunction')
          .addToUi();
    }

  function mainFunction() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().sort(4, false);
      automateSheetCheck();
    }

  function automateSheetCheck(){
      var d = new Date();
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var currentRow = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getLastRow(); //Get the last row with value on your sheet data as a whole to only scan rows with values
      for(var x =2; x<=currentRow; x++){ //Loop starts at row 2
        if(spreadsheet.getRange("D"+x).getValue() == ""){ //Checks if D (row# or x) value is null
          Logger.log("Cell D"+x+" is empty"); //Logs the result for review
        }else{
          var res = spreadsheet.getRange("C"+x).getValue() + spreadsheet.getRange("D"+x).getValue(); //SUM of C & D values
          if(spreadsheet.getRange("D"+x).getValue() > 0){ // If D value is greater than 0, E cell is updated with new timestamp and then C value is replaced with res
            Logger.log("Updated Timestamp on cell E"+x + " because D"+x+ " with value of "+ spreadsheet.getRange("D"+x).getValue() +" is greater than 0"); //Logs the result for review
            spreadsheet.getRange("E"+x).setValue(formattedDate);
            spreadsheet.getRange("C"+x).setValue(res); //Replace C value with "res"
            spreadsheet.getRange("D"+x).setValue(""); //remove D value
          }else{ // If D value is less than 0, F cell is updated with a new timestamp
            Logger.log("Updated Timestamp on cell F"+x + " because D"+x+ " with value of "+ spreadsheet.getRange("D"+x).getValue() +" is less than 0"); //Logs the result for review
            spreadsheet.getRange("F"+x).setValue(formattedDate);
            spreadsheet.getRange("C"+x).setValue(res); //Replace C value with "res"
            spreadsheet.getRange("D"+x).setValue(""); //remove D value
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**RESULT:**

After running the script, the will be the result on the sample sheet:

[image]

Here's the Execution Logs, where that you can review what happened after running the code:

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! The notation to increment the cell row (`"F"+x`) was something I honestly didn't think would work, but I'm glad it actually did. Although I do have a lot of data to go through, I'll be editing like 5 or 6 at once, max, so the time it takes to check the null cells won't hurt a bit. And the UI menu also helped a lot, since I'm sharing this with co-workers who have limited knowledge when it comes to spreadsheets and macros. Thank you once again for the help.