# How to attach a timestamp column to archive data script

Tags: google-sheets

I have this script which will update daily in the morning. Is there a way to add a timestamp so that it will automatically insert when it was processed?

```
function archive5() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ji3Q02uOyrDXyrl7LcghWLcLjz-CeSUgSCU7QD0BVEk'); 
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Allergen Planner'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('T21:U25') 
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1j_Hy2GDKE-5dJVKSeBx0qFIWHOsvZpCTBm-SgPz7MSs');
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Post Process Historical Data'); 

 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,2,5,2).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()

}
```

Comment: you can add timeshtamp to your `data = range.getValues().map(function (rowData) {return rowData.push(new Date() )} )`

Comment: Thanks, where would I put that in the code? Im sorta new to java. Just include that in the 4th variable line?

Comment: Ive tried inputing it everywhere which contains Data and am coming up with this message every time 

"Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues."

Comment: The push method is not quite the result you want, so it's better to use the following code `data = range.getValues().map(function(arrRow){return arrRow.concat([new Date()]) } )` You should also change the code for inserting the data array on the final sheet because the original size of the array changes after we add a column with a timeshtamp to it `ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,2,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you update your spreadsheet - or it updates itself - a function to update its data is called, right? So what you can do is just use
`ss.getRange(<timestamp_cell>).setValue(new Date())`.

However, if what you need is updating some specific and yet not fix row (e.g. any row on C column, depending on certain conditions), you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67287644/how-can-i-search-for-edited-rows-on-sheets-to-compare-the-values-and-change-the), which was very well answered, and I improved a bit.

Without the spreadsheet or a little more information about what you're trying to achieve, that's the best I can help you.