# Static timestamping in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, spreadsheet

I am trying to add STATIC timestamp to my data whenever it is imported or pasted in the sheets.

I am using this formula now

```
(=ARRAYFORMULA( IFS(I1:I="","",L1:L="",NOW(),TRUE,L1:L)))
```

but, whenever I open the sheet again the time gets changed automatically to the current time as i am using the `now()` function. I tried `on-Edit` in the script, but it's only working when the data is manually entered.

Is there any other way I can use to static timestamp when data is being pasted or imported?

Comment: Can we know how is your data is being "pasted or imported" given that `onEdit` trigger does not work for your case?

Comment: i am using importrange function to import some data from different sheet , and when its populating the sheet with data my onEdit trigger is not working , even when i paste those data manually then also no trigger , so only when i make a change manually  then it get triggered , is there any alternative to that. i just want to time stamp which is non volatile

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `NOW()` on the formula, do it via script using `new Date()`.

The `NOW()` function updates the timestamp *every time* the spreadsheet is open or something changes in it, while the `new Date()` gives you a full (date and time) and static timestamp.

Also, as I've seen on the comments of your question, there really is no way to use `onEdit()` through automated scripts and macros.

Comment: i am using this
unction todaysDate() {
  var td = new Date();
  return  td.getDate() + "/" + (td.getMonth() + 1)+ "/" + td.getFullYear() + " " + td.getHours() + ":" + td.getMinutes() + ":" + td.getSeconds();
}
to get static date , now my problem is its also get updated when ever i open it or sign in again can you give me a alternative scrip

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

You can use a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to return the actual date with the method [new Date()](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates) and the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties). Open [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and paste the following function:

### Code

```
function getTimestamp(reset) {

  // update the timestamp
  if (reset == 1) {
    setTime()
  }

  // try-catch structure in order to set the time in the first execution
  try {
    var time = ScriptProperties.getProperty('time')
  }
  catch (err) {
    setTime()
    var time = ScriptProperties.getProperty('time')
  }

  return time

}

function setTime() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var time = new Date()
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('time', time)
}
```

### How it works

Now, you can use it in any cell like another [Sheet function](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en). Call the function with `=getTimestamp(0)`. On the first execution, it tries to get the saved [property](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties) `time`, but as the property does not exist it generates a timestamp and saves a new property in the project with the key `time` and the value of the timestamp.

In the following executions, the value obtained by the function when it is recalculated is the same, since the property is not overwritten unless the function is called with a `1` input: `=getTimestamp(1)`. In this case, the timestamp is updated, but if it is not set back to `=getTimestamp(0)`, every time the function is recalculated (which happens automatically every so often) the timestamp will change.

In conclusion, always use `=getTimestamp(0)`. When you want to update the value, change it to `=getTimestamp(1)` and go back to the original formula.

### update

I have updated the answer to explain how to update the timestamp when new values are added:

1. Use a cell as input to the function, e.g. `=getTimeStamp(A1)` 2.
2. Create an onEdit trigger
3. Check that the range of the `e` event belongs to new values.
4. Update the value of `A1` to 1 and then to 0 if you have detected new values.

### example:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A4')
  if (range.columnStart > 1 && range.rowStart > 10){
    cell.setValue(1)
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    cell.setValue(0)
  }
}
```

If new values are added from column 1 and row 10, `A1` is updated to `1` and then to `0`, thus updating the value of the timeStamp function and saving it permanently until the trigger is executed again.

### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Working with Dates and Times](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates)
- [Apps Script: Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the answer and i am sure it will work but i am not able to figure it out ,i want the time stamp to change when new values are added but i want to keep the previous time stamp when its not changing , can you help me write down the formula.

Comment: So you want it to update the timestamp based on *another* cell value, so that when it changes, your timestamp does too? You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67287644/how-can-i-search-for-edited-rows-on-sheets-to-compare-the-values-and-change-the)

Comment: You cannot get _permanent_ timestamps with a custom function, because the formula will get recalculated from time to time. Further, because you save only one property and share it between all instances of your custom function, all cells where you have the custom function formula will eventually show the same timestamp instead of showing individual timestamps per row.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure have your question got a solution. I had the same struggle as yours over the year, **especially with pasted data,** and I found a solution that works for my case nicely (but not by formula, need to run in Apps Script).

Some **background** for my case:

- I have multiple sheets in the spreadsheet to run and generate the
  timestamp
- I want to skip my first sheet without running to generate timestamp
  in it
- I want every edit, even if each value that I paste from Excel to
  generate timestamp
- I want the timestamp to be individual, each row have their own
  timestamp precise to every second
- I don't want a total refresh of the entire sheet timestamp when I am
  editing any other row
- I have a column that is a MUST FILL value to justify whether the
  timestamp needs to be generated for that particular row
- I want to specify my timestamp on a dedicated column only

```
function timestamp() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const totalSheet = ss.getSheets();

  for (let a=1; a<totalSheet.length; a++) {
    let sheet = ss.getSheets()[a];
    let range = sheet.getDataRange();
    let values = range.getValues(); 

    function autoCount() {
      let rowCount;
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        rowCount = i
        if (values[i][0] === '') {
          break;
        }
      }
      return rowCount
    }

    rowNum = autoCount()

    for(let j=1; j<rowNum+1; j++){
      if (sheet.getRange(j+1,7).getValue() === '') {
        sheet.getRange(j+1,7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

1. First, I made a `const totalSheet` with `getSheets()` and run it
   with a `for` loop. That is to identify the total number of sheets
   inside that spreadsheet. Take note, in here, I made `let a=1;`
   supposed all JavaScript the same, starts with `0`, value `1` is to
   **skip the first sheet** and run on the second sheet onwards
2. then, you will notice a function `let sheet = ss.getSheets()[a]`
   inside the loop. Take note, it is not supposed to use `const` if
   your value inside the **variable is constantly changing**, so use
   `let` instead will work fine.
3. then, you will see a `function autoCount()`. That is to make a `for`
   loop to count the number of rows that have values edited in it. The
   `if (values[i][0] === '')` is to navigate the script to search
   through the entire sheet that has value, looking at the row `i` and
   the column `0`. Here, the `0` is indicating the **first column** of the
   sheet, and the `i` is the row of the sheet. Yes, it works like a
   `json` object with `panda` feeling.
4. then, you found the number of rows that are edited by running the
   `autoCount()`. Give it a `rowNum` variable to contain the result.
5. then, pass that `rowNum` into a new `for` loop, and use `if (sheeet.getRange(j+1,7).getValue() === '')` to determine which row
   has not been edited with timestamp. Take note, where the `7` here
   indicating the **7th column** of the sheet is the place that I want a
   timestamp.
6. inside the `for` loop, is to `setValue` with date in a specified
   format of `("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`. You are free to edit into any
   style you like
7. ohya, do remember to deploy to activate the trigger with event type
   as `On Change`. That is not limiting to edit, but for all kinds of
   changes **including paste**.

Here's a screenshot on how it would look like:

[image: First Column Value 7th Column Timestamp]

Lastly, please take note on some of my backgrounds before deciding to or not to have the solution to work for your case. Cheers, and happy coding~!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a *permanent* timestamp with a spreadsheet formula, even with a named function or an Apps Script custom function, because formula results refreshed from time to time. When the formula gets recalculated, the original timestamp is lost.

The easiest way to insert the current date in a cell is to press **Control + ;** or **⌘;**. See the [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) help page.

You can also use an `onEdit(e)` script to create permanent timestamps. Search this forum for `[google-apps-script] timestamp` to find many examples.